# C ADT : *.c file inclusion

Tags: c++, c, include, adt

I have an abstract structure :

[trame.h]

```
typedef struct s_trame t_trame;

// Allocation, setters and getters prototypes
```

[/trame.h]

[trame.c]

```
# include "trame.h"

struct s_trame
{

}

// Allocation, setters and getters implementations
```

[/trame.c]

In an other file, I need to know the fields in t_trame. The only way I found to do that is to include the trame.c file. How bad is it in this specific context or how to do it better ?

[main.c]

```
# include "trame.h"

# include "trame.c"

int main()
{

t_trame trame;

// Do something with trame

return 0;

}
```

[/main.c]

I don't really want to break the abstraction, but I would prefer using the structure for some of my implementations.

Comment: Why not just fully declare the structure in the header?

Comment: Because I would lose the opaciticy everywhere else.

Comment: But you think about including the whole .c file? You lose opacity when you want to access members (what you currently want to do), not by declaring them in your header file.

Comment: Yeah but here I choose to. If I had only included the .h file, it would work just fine with pointer (typically this is what I do everywhere else)

Comment: The only benefit I see from not declaring it in the header is, that you don't have to recompile projects including the header when the structure changes (and in case you only used pointers to the structure, not even then, so this isn't really a good point). Anything else of what can be done without a complete type can be done with a complete one as well. Again, you lose opacity by accessing your structure, _not_ by letting the compiler see the definition.

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty common method of black-boxing structures in C. But to make the structures *really* opaque, you should wrap all access to the structure, including creation and destruction, in functions.

Like

```
t_trame *trame_create();  /* Allocates and initializes the structure */
void trame_destroy(t_trame *);  /* Frees the structure */

void trame_do_something(t_trame *, int some_argument);  /* Does something with the structure */

int trame_get_some_data(t_trame *);  /* Returns some data from the structure */
```

etc.

Then no code using the structure needs to see the actual structure, it will just have a pointer to it, and needs to call your functions to do any operations on the structure.

Comment: Yeah, I have all that. The fact is that in another structure I want to use the structure not its pointer and precisely I don't want to depend on a dynamic allocation (let's say for real time concern).

Comment: @user3020921 To use the actual structure and not a pointer to it, you need the full definition of the structure, which you don't have. You can solve this by having *two* header files: One public that is normal used, and a "private" that is used internally by your code and which includes the actual structure definition. If you need to use the structure and not a pointer, include the private header file. Do note that it breaks the whole black-box wide open, and that you might want to think about a design where you don't need the structure.

Comment: I agree, this is the only solution I could come up with.